# how to capture the java version on linux machine

Tags: linux, command-line, awk, java

how to capture the java version on linux redhat machine

we tried that:

```
java -version | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g'
```

but we get

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

while expected output should be

```
1.8.0_65
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java -version` outputs to its standard error, so you need to redirect that:

```
java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g'
```

You can do this with a single AWK invocation:

```
java -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR==1 {gsub("\"", "", $NF); print $NF}'
```

Comment: we can also do it on remote machine as  ssh $IP "java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk '{print \$NF}' | sed 's/\"//g' "

Comment: well done step , this is one of the best answer I have seen